# Powershell find and move items

Tags: powershell, find, move

Hey there i need to move a lot of files using a powershell script and i kinda need help on this one.

The root is as following

```
> tree .
\
├───Folder1
│   ├───Sub1
│   │   └───Stockfile
│   └───Sub2
└───Folder2
    ├───Sub1
    │   └───Stockfile
    └───Sub2
```

The script needs to find the stockfiles and need to move them to the Sub2 folder of each mainfolder.

I made the following script to show all the stockfiles in a list:

```
$var = get-childitem -Filter *stock* -recurse
foreach ($file in $var) {
write-host ($file.FullName)
}
```

Comment: Is the name of the `Sub2` folder consistent?  How do you 'know' the name of the destination folder?  Is it explicitly named `Sub2` always?

Comment: The folders aren't named Sub1 and Sub2. There are like 400 folders starting with TM and then 6 random numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *_stock.csv |
  Move-Item -WhatIf -Destination { $_.FullName -replace '^(.*)\\Sub1\\','$1\Sub2\' }
```

The approach extracts the path prefix up to `...\Sub1` from the full path of each stock file and makes `...\Sub2` the destination (directory) path.

That way, stock files are moved from anywhere in the `...\Sub1` subtree directly into `...\Sub2`.

Note:

- `-WhatIf` shows you what *would* happen first; remove it to perform actual moving.
- The assumption is that the stock file paths contain only *one* `Sub1` component, and that there are no stock files with duplicate names in the `Sub1` subtree.
- `-replace` interprets its first operand as a *regular expression*, which is why the `\` chars. must be escaped as `\\` in order to be recognized as literals; characters in the actual folder name could also require escaping (but don't in this case).

  - If you don't know the folder name in advance, you can safely escape it with `[regex]::Escape($folderName)`

Comment: Ok i removed the -WhatIf, because it seems to work. But without the -WhatIf statement i get the following message:

Comment: Move-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
[Move-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: Ok it works now, the next challange is to move files from folders starting with TM*. So the folder names are like TM123456, TM456789 and so on. In those folders are the 2 subfolders. How to move files from folders starting with TM?

Comment: I just realized it can be done without a loop or ForEach-Object altogether, using a ScriptBlock parameter - please see my update.

Comment: As for the follow-up question re `TM*` folders: please post it as a _new_ question (and feel free to let me know here once you've done so).

Answer (score 2):

Assume folders are all called sub1 and sub2.

```
$var = get-childitem -Filter *stock* -recurse
foreach ($file in $var) {
    $parent = Split-Path $file.fullname -parent
    Move-Item $file.FullName -destination $parent\..\sub2\1.txt
}
```

I know this is not pretty, but it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made it work this way, thanks a lot.

```
    $var = get-childitem -Filter *_stock.csv -recurse
foreach ($file in $var)
 { Move-Item $file.FullName ($file.FullName -replace '^(.*)\\Sub1\\','$1\Sub2\') }
```